# How to set N conditions for a logical operator and/or in OpenLayers3?

Tags: openlayers-3

Currently both and/or logical filters allow two conditions (binary):

```
new ol.format.ogc.filter.Or(conditionA, conditionB)
```

Is there any simple way to append N conditions? Something like:

```
new ol.format.ogc.filter.Or([conditions])
```

Answer (score 0):

Openlayers3 does not have such a function at the moment, so I ended up writing a simple recursive function like:

```
var ol3Filter = createOrFilter(features, 0);
```

.......

```
function createOrFilter(features, index){

    if (index === features.length - 1)
        return ol.format.ogc.filter.bbox('the_geom', features[index].getGeometry().getExtent(), srsProjectionStr);

    return new ol.format.ogc.filter.Or(ol.format.ogc.filter.bbox('the_geom', features[index].getGeometry().getExtent(), srsProjectionStr),
            createOrFilter(features, index + 1));

}
```